# Perl return up levels control

Tags: perl

Assuming I have the code below:

```
sub level1 {
    print "before level 1 \n";
    level2();
    print "after level 1 \n";
}

sub level2 {
    print "before level 2 \n";
    level3();
    print "after level 2 \n";
}

sub level3 {
    print "before level 3 \n";
    level4();
    print "after level 3 \n";
}

sub level4 {
    print "before level 4 \n";
    #break_nested();
    print "after level 4 \n";
}

print level1();
```

If you run this code, the output will be:

```
before level 1 
before level 2 
before level 3 
before level 4 
after level 4 
after level 3 
after level 2 
after level 1
```

I want to return from the sub level4 direct to the main package so the output should be:

```
before level 1 
before level 2 
before level 3 
before level 4
```

I found on cpan a module called [Sub::Uplevel](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Sub-Uplevel-0.24/lib/Sub/Uplevel.pm) but not what I want.

I found also [Scope::Upper](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Scope-Upper-0.24/lib/Scope/Upper.pm)  and [Return::MultiLevel](http://search.cpan.org/~mauke/Return-MultiLevel-0.03/lib/Return/MultiLevel.pm)  but do not know how to use them for this purpose.

Can we use the caller and know how many frames and clear the top frame or select specific frame and return to it.

Please note, I can not use goto labels as the actual program is divided into modules and files.

Comment: This is an extraordinary design. I hope you have a good reason for it?

Comment: That's what exceptions are for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such control flow is usually a really bad idea. But we can do this, using fatal exceptions:

```
use feature 'say';

sub level1 {
   say "1 enter";
   level2();
   say "1 leave";
}

sub level2 {
   say "2 enter";
   die "I want to break free";
   say "2 leave";
}

use Try::Tiny; # better than bare "eval"

say "before try";
try {
    level1();
};
say "after try";
```

Output:

```
before try
1 enter
2 enter
after try
```

---

Reading through Scope::Upper documentation, it appears that you can do an equivalent thing with `unwind`:

```
use feature 'say';
use Scope::Upper qw/unwind CALLER/;

sub level1 {
   say "1 enter";
   level2();
   say "1 leave";
}

sub level2 {
   say "2 enter";
   unwind CALLER 1;
   say "2 leave";
}

say "before call";
level1();
say "after call";
```

Output:

```
before call
1 enter
2 enter
after call
```

But please do not use such features unless that's the whole point of your code: It makes for difficult to debug problems otherwise.

Comment: using the module Scope::Upper as you used seems ok. I used unwind CALLER xxx and found it is no problem if I use unwind CALLER 100 for example to make sure I will return to the main package whatever the nested subs. Is there a way to know the callers frame size and make the unwind CALLER caller_frame size to just exactly return to the main package with the correct size even if it does not matter as I see.

Comment: @daliaessam To find the absolute top: `my $i; $i++ while caller $i; unwind CALLER($i - 1)`. To find the main package: `my @frame; my $i; $i++ while @frame = caller $i and $frame[0] ne "main"; unwind CALLER(@frame ? $i : $i - 1)` – or something weird like that. Such an action is very unlikely to be useful in a maintainable way. [Miller's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22595950/1521179) is a good solution to use if you value your sanity.

Comment: I think this is what I want. I have a reason for using this coding style, this question indeed is the answer to the unresolved question here [Perl FCGI Exit Without Dieing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773142/perl-fcgi-exit-without-dieing)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifically adding the control mechanisms to each of your subroutines.  For example, say we edit the first 3 subs as follows:

```
sub level1 {
    print "before level 1 \n";
    level2() or return;
    print "after level 1 \n";
}

sub level2 {
    print "before level 2 \n";
    level3() or return;
    print "after level 2 \n";
}

sub level3 {
    print "before level 3 \n";
    level4() or return;
    print "after level 3 \n";
}
```

The output is still the same:

```
before level 1
before level 2
before level 3
before level 4
after level 4
after level 3
after level 2
after level 1
```

However, now edit the `level4` sub as well to indicate that we want to break by [`returning`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) false:

```
sub level4 {
    print "before level 4 \n";
    return; # Break nested loops
    print "after level 4 \n";
}

print level1();
```

Output is now:

```
before level 1
before level 2
before level 3
before level 4
```

If you want to code cleanly, you can add an explicit `return 1;` statement to the end of each of your subroutines.  But ultimately, if you want this type of functionality, just code it by using and reading return codes.